# Close header after outputting

Tags: php, cakephp, header, cakephp-2.3

```
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');

    echo "blabla";

    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array('no-reply@something.com' => 'Something'));
    $Email->to($email);
    $Email->subject('Something');
    $Email->send($textEmail);
```

How can I output and give the file to download before sending an email? Is it possible? Or I have to create a temporary file for that myself? It works if I don't send an email.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: @thaJeztah the latest

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

1. Create the file and save it to a tempoary location
2. Send the email with the attachment (using the code you posted in your question)
3. Use low-level PHP methods to write file contents to HTTP stream ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175533/how-to-return-a-file-in-php))
4. Finally, delete the tempoary file

I think by the looks of the code you've posted, you're nearly there, just got to sort the order out.

I hope this helps.