# Download Code Error In PHP? Upload And Download Form

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and tried to create a simple php upload and download script connecting to mysql databse. I used uid() to generate a special id for each file and stored it the database. I am almost done but the problem is I could not figure out how to write the download.php code?
Please help me. I am sharing my index.php, upload.php and download.php current files.

My index.html has this form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

My Uploader.php file has this code

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} 
$uid = uniqid();
$filename = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO replitz_file '.
   '(file_uid,file_name) '.
   'VALUES ( "$uid", "$filename" )';

mysql_select_db('replitz');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "http://localhost/Project/download.php?$uid";
mysql_close($conn);
```

And my Download.php code is

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db = mysql_select_db('replitz', $con);
        $file = $_GET['_'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM replitz_files WHERE id='$file_uid'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Link Not Valid: ' . mysql_error());
echo "Link Not Valid";
mysql_close($conn);
```

Now please tell me which code should I use in Download.php to download the file from the  uid() generated code stored in the databse.

Comment: $sql = 'INSERT INTO replitz_file '.
   '(file_uid,file_name) '.
   'VALUES ( "$uid", "$filename" )';
it is a valid query  for MySQL ????
I think it should 
$sql = "INSERT INTO replitz_file ".
   "(file_uid,file_name) ".
   "VALUES ( '$uid', '$filename' )";

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file direct from your dowload.php by specifying a custom header and using readfile to include the file. Checkout this stack question:
[How to return a file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175533/how-to-return-a-file-in-php)