# Retrieving (text, image) pair from server in fastest time?

Tags: database

I'd like to retrieve a text file and an image from the server quickly: the text files are named data*.txt and the images are img*.png. A typical request would be "retrieve Kth pair," and the server would respond with (dataK.txt, imgK.png). What is the fastest way to do this?

I'm using the LAMPPP and TCP/IP stacks. The files reside directly on the filesystem, and the number of pairs is of order 10^5.

Comment: Please provide more details: 1) what kind of server is this? 2) are text and image stored in the database or in file system? 3) how many texts and images are there? 4) over which protocol/connection you want your data being transported?

Answer (score 0):

If expected number of incoming requests is **< 1 req/sec**, then there's no need for optimization. Implement two separate handlers - one for text, another for image.
[This answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175618/2444130) shows how to implement a handler for binary file (in PHP).
Respectively, you will need to send two separate requests.

If expected number of incoming requests is **significantly higher than 1 req/sec**, then some research should be done. You would need to a) profile your web-application under load b) learn caching techniques, decide which one is better c) consider using in-between caching proxy d) think of minimizing number of requests etc. etc.